# Merge Lists but Keep Relative Index Order

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

I'm not sure how to articulate this problem precisely, but here is a try:

Given N ordered (not sorted!) lists of elements (inputs), I want to merge them into a new list and remove as many duplicates as possible (output). The constraint is: Given any two elements a = x_i and b = x_j from one of the input lists, if i < j in the input list, then there must exist a = x_p, b = x_q in the merged list such that p < q.

```
Example 1:
L1 = (a, b)
L2 = (b, a)
Merged = (a, b, a) or (b, a, b)
```

So here we must have a duplicate to satisfy the constraint.

```
Example 2:
L1 = (a, b)
L2 = (a, b, c)
Merged = (a, b, c) or (a, c, b, c)
```

but (a, b, c) is more optimal since it has the least duplicates.

What is this class of algorithm called? What is the general formulation? What is the optimal solution?

Comment: What's the desired result for L1=(a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b) and L2=(a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b)?

Comment: Can we move away from cryptic `a`, `b` and `c`s and use some actual integer values?

Comment: This is the Shortest Common Supersequence problem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem. There is no efficient solution for a large number of sequences.

Comment: RE: L1=(a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b) and L2=(a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b)?

Good question I didn't clarify. L1 wouldn't be an expected input. The real problem behind this is basically compositing objects in the right order, and compositing (a, a) would just reduce to a. So L1 would be (a, b). So expected output would be (a, b, a).

Comment: @btilly (a,b,a) is not a supersequence of my L2.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah, the latest comment considerably changed the problem from what I thought it was.  The mapping from the initial sequences to the target depends on the elements offered. But you can take all unique 1, 2, and 3 element subsequences without  repeats, view THAT as a set of sequences, and find the shortest common supersequence.

Comment: @Kratos Your last comment confuses me. Doesn't L2 contain `(b, a, b)` as a subsequence? So the answer has to have at least 2 `b`'s with an `a` between them.  Meaning that you'd want `(b, a, b, a)` or `(a, b, a, b)`?

Comment: How big can N be?

Comment: @btilly Ha, I wanted to point out we don't need a supersequence to fulfill the stated constraint, and then I failed to check `(a,b,a)`. Indeed that needs a second `b`. Either that, or we still don't have the full/correct spec (maybe my L2 is invalid as well, but I would've expected them to say so).

Comment: @Kratos If some pair of integers shows up in multiple lists, would you expect the relative order to be flipped in roughly half the lists, or is there some likelihood of consistent ordering better than 1/2? How does the total number of integers compare to the total number of lists?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely a hard problem. Here's my effort to chip away at it.

Say L is the collection of distinct elements across all lists, in arbitrary order. Then concatenating L with itself is a valid (possibly not optimal) solution, because every element is both before and after every element. I.e., for n distinct elements, the optimal solution is between n and 2n.

Some elements don't need to be repeated. One category of these is elements that aren't preceded by other elements in any list, or elements that are only preceded by such elements, and so on. The same goes in the other direction.

We can find these by repeatedly pulling nodes that only appear the the start (or end) of lists, and adding them to the prefix/start (or suffix/end) of the list we're building. We repeatedly do so until we can't, adding successive nodes to the end of the prefix we're building, or the start of the suffix.

E.g.

```
L1 = [a,b,c,d,e]
L2 = [c,b,d,e]
L3 = [a,d]

step 1: prefix = [a], L1 = [b,c,d,e], L2 = [c,b,d,e], L3 = [d]
We can't continue with the prefix, so move on to the suffix
step 2: prefix = [a], suffix = [e], L1 = [b,c,d], L2 = [c,b,d], L3 = [d]
step 3: prefix = [a], suffix = [d,e], L1 = [b,c], L2 = [c,b], L3 = []
We can't continue with the suffix, so we're done with this.
```

Now we have [a, {do something with b & c here}, d, e]

At this stage, the elements we're left with fall between our prefix & suffix, and every element is both before and after at least one other element.

Treat the remaining elements as nodes of a digraph, where there's an arc from one node to another if the corresponding elements are so-ordered in at least one list. E.g., if [a,b,c] are in some list in this order, and haven't been eliminated by the earlier procedure, then they cause us to include arcs (a,b), (a,c), and (b,c).

Every node of this digraph will have arcs in both directions with at least one other node of the digraph. For every such pair, at least one node will have to be repeated.

Find the largest directed acyclic subgraph of this graph. The elements corresponding to these nodes don't need to be repeated. Call these D, and the remaining nodes of the subgraph T.

Then our solution is [prefix, T, D, T, suffix], where the elements corresponding to T are the only ones that get repeated.

Unfortunately, finding the largest induced DAG subgraph is NP-hard. (shown here: https://osf.io/c3gmu/download)

For our toy example, either b or c is a maximum induced DAG, so we can choose either to be S, giving us either:

```
[a,b,c,b,d,e] or
[a,c,b,c,d,e]
```

--- UPDATE ---

Here's a possible approach to approximate the maximum DAG:

- create a set S of all elements not in the prefix or suffix
- create two sets for each element. One containing the set of elements to the left of the element in any list, and the other containing the set of elements to the right of the element in any list. For element t, call these L(t) and R(t) for left & right respectively.

Now we can generate a random induced DAG as follows. Let D be the set of vertices in the DAG, initially empty, L(D) the set of vertices to the left of some element of D in some list, R(D) the set to the right.

1. Move a random vertex v from S to D.
2. Update L(D) & R(D): L(D) = L(D) U L(v), R(D) = R(D) U R(v)
3. Remove the intersection of L(D) and R(D) from S.
4. Repeat as long as |S| > 0

That gets us a random maximal DAG. We can repeat it many times and keep track of the largest to get a large random maximal DAG. To save time, instead of actually modifying S, we can keep track of the set B of 'banned elements' or elements that would be removed from S in this algorithm.